# One click project tree

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way in Intellij 12 to open a file in the project tree with one click? I'm coming from text-mate to intellij and I'd like to only have to click on an item once for it to appear in the editing screen.

If there is a benefit to having to click it twice then please let me know, but to me it seems like a redundant double click.

I'm using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable "Autoscroll to source" option . You can find it by clicking on the gear icon in the project explorer

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want more control, alt-F1-enter.  Technically 3 clicks, but one motion.

Update:  Requires have "Use all F1, F2, etc keys as standard function keys" to be selected under the Mac Keyboard Preferences.

Comment: Using a MAC, buddy, I think this must be for windows.

Comment: alt/option.  This is the "Select In.." option in the keymaps.

Comment: alt (or option or whatever you want to call it) plus f1 brings up your lcd color panel options from the system preferences.... 

Maybe what has happened here is you use an Eclipse Key Map in Intellij Idea then you've answered my question. I use the mac os keymap in Intellij. 

Anyway, it's wrong and I don't want to mark your answer as wrong so I'm thinking you should clarify it, eg, if you use a keymap from another os such as eclipses, as it's a windows keymap.

Comment: Also, technically that's zero clicks and three keystrokes! Also, it doesn't provide any more control. Sorry for being so pedantic.

Comment: Ok, figured it out.  It is indeed the Mac OS X keymap.  However, on my Mac, i have "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" checked under Keyboard preferences.  Will clarify the original.

Comment: Good man well done for sticking with it, I'll believe you!! There are a lot of people who are almost exclusively keyboard users. I work on a laptop, using the trackpad is part of my way of working. I know desktop users who hate having to reach for the mouse - good tip for them. Cheers for contributing.